# To which class the main(String[] args) actually in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, Object super class doesn't have the main(String[] args) method. Then, which class actually has the main(String[] args) method. How all the classes in Java could access the main(String[] args) method?

Comment: Any class can have a main method, typically though, you would want to try and keep it down to one where possible

Comment: What issue you are getting.  You can write main method in any class of yours.

Comment: The main method is no class member. It is the programms entry point for the operating system. But I also read somewhere that it should reside somewhere as static method

Answer (score 2):

`main` is a static method, so it's not inherited from any super class. Each class can have its own main method.

Answer (score 0):

The 'main' method is the starting point for running Java programs. This is the feature of Java. Almost any class can have this method and be "runnable".